# Geometric random variables $X_1:G(p_1)$ $X_2:G(p_2)$ $X_3:G(p_3)$ are independent, prove the following :

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

$$P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)= \frac{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_2p_3^2}{(1-p_2p_3)(1-p_1p_2p_3)}$$

To be frank I do not know where to start with this question, I would like an idea to get me going, or better yet an answer. This was on an earlier exam, I would like to be ready if something like this were to come up again tomorrow. What makes this a little bit more difficult than usual is the fact that geometric distribution is  a discrete variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  condition on $X_2$:  $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X_1 < X_2 < X_3] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr[X_1 < k < X_3]\Pr[X_2 = k] \\ &\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr[X_1 < k]\Pr[k < X_3]\Pr[X_2 = k]. \end{align*}$$

Comment: what does _ind_ mean above the equality ?

Comment: And I am having difficulties dealing with inequalities here in general

Comment: @JimLowe - *ind* means "by independence."

Comment: @JimLowe I gave you a start.  You should be able to figure out how to proceed from what I have given you.  Any more guidance would amount to simply answering the question for you.