# How do I find $ Pr\{X_1 < k \} $ and $ Pr\{X_1 > k \} $if $X_1 : G(p_1)$- geometric distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

I would think the song like $1-Pr\{X_1 < k \} $ but what is confusing to me is the fact that this is a discrete random variable, and these inequalities ussually apply to absolute continuous variables, so I just don;t know what to do?

I have to prove: Geometric random variables $X_1:G(p_1) X_2:G(p_2) X_3:G(p_3)$ are independent, prove the following :

$$Pr(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)= \frac{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_2p_3^2}{(1-p_2p_3)(1-p_1p_2p_3)}$$

I got started like: 
$$\begin{align*} \Pr[X_1 < X_2 < X_3] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr[X_1 < k < X_3]\Pr[X_2 = k] \\ &\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr[X_1 < k]\Pr[k < X_3]\Pr[X_2 = k]. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Why would going to the probability of the complementary event is appliable only in the continuous case?? Of course not: $\;P(\overline A)=1-P(A)\;$ in any case, and this is usually taught in every introductory course in Probability, usually with discrete variables.

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I can understand how it came off so. I meant in continuous variables finding $Pr(X < t)$ is much more common, so it seems easier to me.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304563/geometric-random-variables-x-1gp-1-x-2gp-2-x-3gp-3-are-independen

Comment: It didnt get an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor correction: as $\Pr[X_1<0]=0$ you must sum through $1\leq k<\infty$ .

$$\begin{align} 
\Pr[X_1 < X_2 < X_3] \;
 &\overset{\text{ind}}{=}\; \sum_{k=\color{darkred}{1}}^\infty \Pr[X_1 < k]\,\Pr[X_2 = k]\,\Pr[X_3 > k]
\\[1ex]
 & = \; \sum_{k=\color{darkred}{1}}^\infty 
\big(
 1-(1-p_1)^{k}
\big)\,\big(
 (1-p_2)^{k}p_2
\big)\,\big(
 (1-p_3)^{k+1}
\big)
\\[1ex]
 & = \; (1-q_2)\,q_3\Big(\sum_{k=\color{darkred}{1}}^\infty 
q_2^{k} \, q_3^{k} -\sum_{k=\color{darkred}{1}}^\infty q_1^k\,q_2^k\,q_3^k\Big) & \text{where } q_n=1-p_n
\\[1ex]
 & = \; (1-q_2)\,q_3\left(\frac{q_2\,q_3}{1-q_2\,q_3} -\frac{q_1\,q_2\,q_3}{(1-q_1\,q_2\,q_3)}\right) & \text{as } \sum_{k=1}^\infty r^k = \frac{r}{1-r}
\\[1ex]
 & = \; (1-q_2)\,q_2\,q_3^2\left(\frac{(1-q_1\,q_2\,q_3)-q_1(1-q_2\,q_3)}{(1-q_1\,q_2\,q_3)}\right)
\\[1ex]
 & = \; \color{purple}{ 
 \frac{(1-q_1)\,(1-q_2)\,q_2\,q_3^2}{(1-q_2\,q_3)\,(1-q_1\,q_2\,q_3)} 
}
\end{align}$$

The suspicion at this point is that you are meant to be using a different definition of geometric distribution than I am used to; one counting successes before the first failure rather than failures before the first success.

It is always important to specify exactly what you mean by a Geometric Distribution, as there are several definitions.